# Notepad++ Copy one character between lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hope you can help me with this...

I have this data file where it's

```
The correct answer is A. and the reason for that answer is ....
ANSWER: 
The correct answer is B. and the reason for that answer is ....
ANSWER: 
The correct answer is C. and the reason for that answer is ....
ANSWER: 
The correct answer is D. and the reason for that answer is ....
ANSWER:
```

I need someway to copy the letter A or B .. etc to the Answer: line

```
The correct answer is A
ANSWER: A
The correct answer is B
ANSWER: B
The correct answer is C
ANSWER: C
The correct answer is D
ANSWER: D
```

Can this be done? to only grab the letter without the dot.?
Thanks

edit: adding the missing info. sorry about that

Comment: Do you want to keep `and the reason for that answer is ...` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex

Find:

```
is (.)(.*)\r\nANSWER:
```

Replace

```
is \1\2\r\nANSWER: \1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fix, it did part of it, however fault on me for not displaying the full issue. The first line doesn't END after the letter A or B etc, it continues to explain why we choose this answer  something like The correct answer is A. for the reason of .....

Comment: whats the full issue?  update your question

Comment: cool, edit your question and put in an example

Comment: edited .. I loved your fix, hope it can be adjusted to extract only the letter.